# Configurable Replica Number in Template using ValueFrom

Tags: continuous-integration, kubernetes, openshift

I have a `template.yml` file that is used when deploying to any OpenShift project. Each project has specific `project-props` `configMap` to be used, this is part of our CICD pipeline, so each project has a unique `project.props` available to it

I would like to be able to control the number of replicas and CPU/Memory limits based on what project I am deploying to. For example a branch testing OpenShift project vs Performance testing OpenShift project would have a different CPU request and limit than an ephemeral OpenShift project.

My `template.yml` file looks something like this:

```
     // <snip>
     spec:
        replicas: "${OS_REPLICAS}"
     // <snip>
     resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "${OS_CPU_LIMIT}"
          memory: "${OS_MEMORY_LIMIT}"
        requests:
          cpu: "${OS_CPU_REQUEST}"
          memory: "${OS_MEMORY_REQUEST}"
     // <snip>
     parameters:
        - name: OS_REPLICAS
          displayName: OS Number of Replicas
          valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
               name: project-props
               key: os.replicas
    // rest of params are similar
```

My relevant `project-props` section is:

```
os.replicas=2
os.cpu.limit=2
os.cpu.request=250m
os.memory.limit=1Gi
os.memory.request=1Gi
```

When I try to deploy this I get the following error:
`quantities must match the regular expression '^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$'`

If I change `template.yml` to have a parameter defined it works fine

```
       parameters:
        - name: OS_REPLICAS
          displayName: OS Number of Replicas
          value: 2
```

It seems that `valueFrom` vs `value` has a different behavior. Is this impossible to do using `valueFrom`? Is there another way I can dynamically change `spec` and `resources` using a `configMap`?

The alternative is to deploy and then use `oc scale dc <deploy_config_name> --replicas=<number>` but it's not very elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, it's does not read the values from the file but at least they can be dynamic.

OpenShift has an `oc process` command that you can be run when using a template.

So this works by doing:

`oc process -f <template_name>.yaml -v <param_name>=<param_value>`

This will over write the parameter value with the one being inserted by `-v`.

An actual example would be

`oc process -f ./src/main/openshift/service.template.yaml -v OS_REPLICAS=2`

You can read more about it [OpenShift template documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/templates.html#generating-a-list-of-objects)

It seems that the OS Origin team does not want to support using files for parameter insertion. You can read more about it here:

https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/10952

https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/10687

Comment: You can also try (tested under Openshift 3.11):
```oc create -f template-file.yaml && new-app --template=$template_name --env REPLICAS_COUNT=$replicas```

Answer (score 2):

Where you have:

```
 spec:
    replicas: "${OS_REPLICAS}"
```

you should have:

```
 spec:
    replicas: "${{OS_REPLICAS}}"
```

With template parameter of:

```
   parameters:
    - name: OS_REPLICAS
      displayName: OS Number of Replicas
      value: 2
```

See:

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-parameters

for use of `"${{}}"`.

What it does is interpret the contents of the parameter as JSON/YAML, rather than a string value. This allows you to supply an integer, which `replicas` requires.

So you don't need `valueFrom`, which wouldn't work anyway as that is only usable for environment variables and not arbitrary fields like `replicas`.

As to trying to set a default for memory and CPU for pods deployed in a project, you should look at having a `LimitRange` resource defined against the project and set a default.

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/dev_guide/compute_resources.html#dev-limit-ranges

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to just hard code the replica value and instead want to read it from a file, configMap or something equivalent so during a deploy depending on the project a different number can be used.

Comment: I know of no way you can do that.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the clear explanation of the difference of usage between ${} and ${{}}.